# In HCL OneTest Data, does admin user has the privileges to change the authorization of user?

Tags: authorization, schema, admin, privileges

Can the admin user change the authorization of any other user in HCL OneTest Data? For example, to change the authorization of the user to view the list of projects.

Answer (score 0):

All the users in HCL OneTest Data have the same privileges.